# how to use regex mix with path variable in app-router

Tags: regex, polymer

I hava a url:

```
<a href="/article/category/catalog/title"></a>
```

[**app-router:**](https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router)

```
<app-route path="/^\/article\/\w+\/\w+/\/:title/i" regex import="/pages/article/content-page.html"></app-route>
```

when i click that url,it should match the router,that is ,article matches article,category matches `\w`,catalog matches `\w`,title matches `:title`,because i want  the title variable passed in to another custom element to query db,how i achieve that?

Comment: Are you having issues with your regular expression, or does the problem lie with `app-router` ?

Comment: when the path pattern is **/^\/article\/\w+\/\w+\/\w+/i** ,it will match that url,but title cannot be a paramer passed to custom element